# How to add special characters in ~/.bashrc file?

Tags: bash, bashrc, alias, special-characters

I am trying to make a bash alias to grep for Git conflicts within files after a merge occurs. Usually on the command line with bash shell, I run `grep -nr '<<<<<<<'`, where the single-quotes are needed to escape the special characters.

My `~/.bashrc` file has this so far:

```
alias confs="grep -nr \'<<<<<<<\'"
```

However, the output when runing `confs` command is

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<<<'.
```

How do I do this? Thanks

Comment: Welcome, Does not `alias confs="grep -nr '<<<<<<<'"` accomplish what you want?
`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very simple thanks to `schrodigerscatcuriosity`. The way to do this would be: `alias confs="grep -nr '<<<<<<<'"`. No extra escape characters are needed